# is it better to pass username and password in soap request directly or in request header in java

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I need to authenticate username and password in every java soap call as clear text, so every request must include user credentials using CXF framework

When a client hits the service call, the user credentials are authenticated using mainframe service and then processes the request if it's authentic.

That is the "easier" but better way to pass the credentials securely?

How bad is it from a security perspective from passing through request as opposed to headers?

Comment: passing credentials via body or header does not make a difference security wise - TLS will encrypt both as it happens a layer beneath http, when not using TLS, anyone intercepting the request will be able to read header just as easy as the request body

Comment: @billdoor TLS this is the default soap implementation am I right?

Comment: soap can work over a multitude of transport protocols, most likely cxf will use http without encryption - i guess the docs can tell you what to do to enable it (look for https / tls / ssl ( = "old name" for tls))